# I am confused with usage about 'the' and object complement

Tags: grammaticality, articles, objects, complements

Is the sentence as below correct in grammar? And is it clear enough?

> Please copy & paste keyword, mykeyword, into the search box of Google
>   Play Store app or website to locate this pure app quickly.

But someone else said the sentence should be something as below:

> Please copy & paste the keyword "mykeyword" into the search box of
>   Google Play Store app or website to locate this pure app quickly.

So, which one is correct?

Comment: The difference is the word "the" prior to "keyword" and the usage of an object complement.

Comment: The correct statement is the latter. The keyword is the  most essential part of sentence and should be presented as prominently as possible. Putting commas on either end of the word suggests that it is extraneous information that could be ignored. Refer to here for proper usage of the comma: http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/comma.html#settingoffnonrestrictiveinformation

Comment: To find our app, search for “mykeyword” in the Google Play Store application.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I know your sentence is right. But is my 1st sentence incorrect? 
Is the expression "...paste keyword, mykeyword, into..." incorrect?

Comment: "...paste keyword, mykeyword, into..." is **not** correct. Hope that helps.

Comment: When issuing written instructions it’s common to omit unnecessary articles. It would be acceptable to write “paste keyword ‘mykeyword’...”.

Comment: Neither is correct and could you please either follow the rules and explain your idea of the rights and wrongs of either and then justify your conclusion, or take the question somewhere such as English Language Learners or preferably, both?

Comment: Thanks  Robbie Goodwin. I just found these two expressions about object complement, mykeyword. But I am not sure which one is correct in grammar. But you said neither is correct. Why? Thank you for more detail explaining.

Answer (score -1):

The first one is correct. The second sentence may be out of context, suggesting to physically paste the keyboard you are typing on.  If you do, I recommend using paper glue to minimize the damages.